R dbplyr percentages not calculated correctly from live connection to Microsoft SQL Server
I have a Microsoft SQL Server database which I have connected to with an ODBC link. There are three columns of interest in the table I am querying: serovar, reportyear and hospitalised.
Each row represents one case. I want to collect an aggregated summary table into R where each row is a serovar, each column is a reportyear and each cell value represents the percentage hospitalised.
For example, if there were a total of 3 cases of serovar x in 2020, and only 2 were hospitalised, I would expect the percentage value in the cell to be 66.67%.
Here is some example data:
# Create example data:
dt <- data.frame(
  pid = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 
  serovar = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "y"), 
  reportyear = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021), 
  hospitalised = c("Y", "Y", "N", "N", NA, "Y", NA, "N"))

# Output:
> dt
  pid serovar reportyear hospitalised
1   1       x       2020            Y
2   2       x       2020            Y
3   3       x       2020            N
4   4       x       2021            N
5   5       y       2020         <NA>
6   6       y       2020            Y
7   7       y       2021         <NA>
8   8       y       2021            N

My lazy connection to the database is called db:
# Create lazy connection to database:
db <- tbl(con, 
          category = params$category, 
          schema = "clean", 
          table = viewname)


Then I select the relevant columns, filter the data and calculate the percentage hospitalised:
summarytab <- db %>% 
  
  # Select required columns:
  select(serovar, reportyear, hospitalised) %>% 
  
  # Re-code hospital:
  mutate(hospitalised_tf = case_when(
    hospitalised == "Y" ~ TRUE,
    hospitalised == "N" ~ FALSE, 
    .default = NA
  )) %>%
  
  # Filter rows by year:
  filter(between(reportyear, 2020, 2024)
         & !is.na(serovar) 
         & !is.na(reportyear)
         & !is.na(hospitalised_tf)) %>%
  
  # Group by serovar and year:
  group_by(serovar, reportyear) %>% 
  
  # Calculate total cases and number hospitalised by serovar and year:
  summarise(total_cases = n(),
            hosp_sum = sum(hospitalised_tf, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  
  # Calculate percentage hospitalised:
  mutate(hosp_pct = (hosp_sum/total_cases)*100) %>%
  
  # Arrange by year and serovar:
  arrange(serovar, reportyear) %>%
  
  # Collect to check results:
  collect()

If I run this code on a normal data.frame within R, I get the expected result:
> summarytab
# A tibble: 4 × 5
# Groups:   serovar [2]
  serovar reportyear total_cases hosp_sum hosp_pct
  <chr>        <dbl>       <int>    <int>    <dbl>
1 x             2020           3        2     66.7
2 x             2021           1        0      0  
3 y             2020           1        1    100  
4 y             2021           1        0      0

The problem is that the live database connection gives me 0s or 100s in the percentage column instead of the actual percentage. So I'm assuming something about the conversion to SQL is not right, but can't figure out what.  Here is the SQL query:
show_query(summarytab)
<SQL>
SELECT "q01".*, ("hosp_sum" / "total_cases") * 100.0 AS "hosp_pct"
FROM (
  SELECT
    "serovar",
    "reportyear",
    COUNT(*) AS "total_cases",
    SUM("hospitalised_tf") AS "hosp_sum"
  FROM (
    SELECT "q01".*
    FROM (
      SELECT
        "q01".*,
        CASE
WHEN ("hospitalised" = 'Y') THEN 1
WHEN ("hospitalised" = 'N') THEN 0
ELSE NULL
END AS "hospitalised_tf"
      FROM (
        SELECT
          "Serotype" AS "serovar",
          "DateUsedForStatisticsYear" AS "reportyear",
          "Hospitalisation" AS "hospitalised"
        FROM "FWD"."clean"."SALM_Case"
      ) "q01"
    ) "q01"
    WHERE ("reportyear" BETWEEN 2020.0 AND 2024.0 AND NOT(("serovar" IS NULL)) AND NOT(("reportyear" IS NULL)) AND NOT(("hospitalised_tf" IS NULL)))
  ) "q01"
  GROUP BY "serovar", "reportyear"
) "q01"
ORDER BY "serovar", "reportyear"
> 

There seems to be a lot of repetition in the query, and the percentage calculation is at the top, which seems strange to me - but I can't see any issues with the way the calculation itself has been written.
I would be grateful for an explanation as to why I get a correct result when the percentage calculation is done in the R environment, but an incorrect result when I try to do the calculation via SQL query on the server.

Have to cast one of the fields, 100 / 200 is 0 in sql server, while 100.0 / 200 is 0.5

Try 100e0 * hosp_sum / total_cases AS hosp_pct, to concisely force float calculations and scale the result.  Side note: Why all the quoted identifiers? Is that an R thing?

^ quoted identifiers not an R thing, but I presume a dbplyr robust-translation-of-dplyr-to-sql thing.

I wonder why people keep reinventing a worse sql syntax to avoid writing the easier version

To clarify @siggemannen the idea behind dbplyr is that you can use R dplyr code to write queries, which are then translated into SQL by the package.  It is for the convenience of not having to switch languages in a script which can be especially useful if sharing the script with colleagues who are only just getting used to R.  The function 'show_sql()' simply reveals dbplyr's SQL translation of the R code.  This is not how I would have written it myself in SQL  - but a good reason for using dbplyr should be not having to worry about SQL idiocyncracies like the float problem mentioned above.

@siggemannen could you explain more about the decimal point issue that you mentioned  in your first comment and present it as an answer?  For information, the columns 'hosp_sum' and 'total_cases' are numeric (at least I assumed they were - if integer I can always do as.numeric() to force them to be, but would be good to understand the reasoning behind this issue).

I added a duplicate which you can read, but basically, sql server does integer division if both sides of the expressions are integers, so one have to cast one of the arguments into a float or numeric to get it to calculate things correctly. This might not be natural from the pure math point of view but it's how things work. Same problem arise when one does AVG on integer columns.

About dplyr, i understand the thought behind it, but the problem is that these libs don't quite make it because of the differences in actual db vendor implementations, for example, it didn't figure out that one needed to do the cast and you have to do it yourself. Eventually one hits a case where this lib can't generate good or fast code, and you are forced to write real sql anyway

Thanks - I think there is an additional element to this issue which is that R and SQL handle this problem differently.  It seems that if you make a calculation which results in an integer in R, it is stored more flexibly so will return a numeric result if further calculations are done on it and the result happens to be fractional, whereas I guess that SQL is more focused on memory saving strategies, therefore defaults to sticking with integers unless you expressly tell it you want a numeric result.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@siggemannen's comment helped me identify the solution - so putting this here in case anyone comes across the same difficulty.
The crux of the issue is that the inputs to the percentage calculation (columns hosp_sum and total_cases) are all whole numbers, and are therefore being stored as integers.  As explained in this Stack Overflow post numbers stored as numeric can take up more space than integers, because they are stored in two pieces (see here for a demonstration of size differences between integers and numeric in R).
SQL is designed to interact with databases and therefore prioritises space saving / computation time over mathematical convenience.  Because I supplied two integers as inputs to the percentage calculation, it defaulted to providing an integer as the result - either rounding up or down (hence the 0s and 100s). As @siggemannen points out, just converting one of the two input numbers from integer to numeric is sufficient to force the result to be stored as numeric as well. I can do this with dbplyr using the base R as.numeric() function and then pass this directly to the percentage calculation, keeping it all on the SQL server:
  # Calculate total cases and number hospitalised by serovar and year:
  summarise(total_cases = as.numeric(n()),
            hosp_sum = sum(hospitalised_tf, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%

  # Calculate percentage hospitalised:
  mutate(hosp_pct = round((hosp_sum/total_cases)*100, digits = 2)) %>%

  # Arrange by year and serovar:
  arrange(reportyear, serovar) %>% 

  # Select columns:
  select(serovar, reportyear, hosp_pct) %>% 
  
  # Collect the resultant table in a data.frame:
  collect()


This gives me the correct numeric result (i.e. 2/3 cases hospitalised = 66.67%).
R, on the other hand, prioritises flexibility and numeric accuracy, which is why it will present the fractional result of a calculation as numeric, even when both inputs were stored as integers. As explained in this dbplyr vignette:

R and SQL have different defaults for integers and reals. In R, 1 is a real, and 1L is an integer. In SQL, 1 is an integer, and 1.0 is a real

Also in R, integers are 'a special case of numeric' while in SQL, integers and real numbers (SQL-speak for numeric) are completely separate data types.

Do you have any reference to back up your claim that this behaviour is due to space saving?

@DaleK I can find discussions about this that all come to the same conclusion (that it is about SQL server being for managing relational databases and therefore performance, versus R which is for statistics) but I have not yet been able to find an official SQL documentation that highlights this rationale.  It makes logical sense though.  I was using the term memory interchangeably with performance and computational speed as for practical purposes less speed is always due to a process taking up more memory.

I don't believe its anything to do with space saving... I believe its due to SQL having been defined that when carrying out maths functions on ints, the result is an int.

@DaleK the underlying reason for restricting maths functions carried out on integers to only result in integers must be space saving though as mathematically returning an integer as an answer to e.g. 5/10 is not accurate.  This seems logical to me as although SQL servers and R can both store data and do some maths, the main point of an SQL server is data storage not maths, and the main point of R is to do maths, not data storage.
